# How to reference multiple buttons to do the same thing in Android

Tags: java, android, for-loop

What I am trying to do is have all those buttons do the same thing when I click them individually. I am just transferring over from C#.net so I am not sure how exatly to do it. I have all the buttons android:onClick set to "UserPush" but I don't know what to do from there. I am also trying to have them disable when pushed.

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {

    Button A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);

        A1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A1);
        A2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A2);
        A3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A3);
        B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1);
        B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2);
        B3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B3);
        C1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C1);
        C2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C2);
        C3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C3);
    }

    public void UserPush() {
        for(Button c : GameScreen.class) {
            c.Disable
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what you want to achieve is creating many button with same action and the action is disable all the button?

Comment: You need View v parameter inside the UserPush() method to work.

Comment: nayoso , yes and some other stuff but i can figure that out if i could just no how to do this

Comment: and joao2fast4u , i tryed and Game.class becomes red

Comment: You need to check what the red underline says, then

Comment: i hade to take out the for statmint! all good thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, You can do something like this:

```
public void UserPush(View v){
   ((Button)v).setEnabled(false);
}
```